# add model value in class name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to figure this simple thing but I'm actually embarrassed to ask such a newbie question. Im so used to mvc2 and i jumped into my first mvc3 project some days ago. anyway the question is how can i add model value in a class name or id

```
<div class="remove-MODEL.ID">body...</div>
```

in mvc2 its simple

```
<div class="remove-<%= Model.Id %>">body...</div>
```

my current code and try is (WORKS)

```
<div class="remove-@Model.Id">body...</div>
```

i tried a string format instead (WORKS)

```
<div class="@string.format("{0}", Model.Id)">body...</div>
```

i really have no idea and like i said such a simple thing becomes the hardest :)

**EDIT**

It is really odd but my third and forth suggestion worked after a couple of tries

**Erik Philips** answer got info about this issue.

Comment: If you are using the razor view-engine, your suggestion `<div class="remove-@Model.Id">body...</div>` looks fine. Do you get any errors?

Comment: no error it just writes the html like it is in the view, `remove-@Model.Id` it does not take the model value.

Comment: Can you print anything else from the model on to the page?

Comment: everything worked just fine now when i used the `@string.Format("remove-{0}", Model.Id)`, really odd but hey it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the minor *limitations* of the Razor engine.  The problem lies in the engines ability to determine if the @ is razor syntax or just regular html text.  This example can occur frequently when the razor output is `<prefixvalue>@<model>.<value>` because that is similar to the email expression `<name>@<emailprovider>.com`.  You can force the engine to assume razor syntax by surrounding the expression in parentheses (e.g. `@(model.id)`).

Answer (score 1):

In my project, I am using this code:

```
<div class="remove_@Model.ElementAt(0).id">body...</div>
```

And it works well.

Comment: yes i use that for mvc2 to but for mvc3 its not the same syntax when using razor